# TexStudio getting error

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

[image]

Hello guys. I have a thesis template and when I try to add for example 1.2 Literature Review under Introduction Part of .toc file, I get this error. I try to edit it in thesis.toc file which I find it more appropiate but somehow when I change a single line of it, I get this error. After I get this error and clicking yes, I reliaze i didnt edit it and returned to original state.

Can somebody help or explain how to get rid of this? Im not used to use TexStudio.
[image]

Comment: Don't manually edit the toc file, this gets overwritten everytime you compile your document.

Comment: As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says, you're using LaTeX wrong. (And it doesn't have anything to do with TeXstudio, your editor.) If you want the ToC entry to be different than the header of that section, use the optional argument: `\section[Entry for ToC]{Entry for section heading}`. Many of the usual document classes provide this option.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz so how i am suppose to add a section or delete section that have been already created in .toc file?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel im afraid it doesnt work the way you are telling me... because there are a lot of sections that have been already created in .toc file which need to be replaced with my thesis titles

Comment: @ichbinberk You add or remove the `\section` in the .tex file and compile two times. On the first compilation this will add/remove the section from the .toc file and in the second compilation it will show the updated table of contents in your document.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz % CONTENTS AND LIST OF FIG AND TABLE PAGES
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
These are the things in the .tex file . The things that have written in the table of contents as default does not appear in .tex file so I cannot re-rewrite all the table of contents materials in .tex file

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz please check the last image I added, I hope it is clear.

Comment: The last image shows that latex can't find some images. You should fix this problem first as it prevents latex from compiling your document. Check if the folder with the image is there.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i know i can just put them into comment line and that does not solve my problem after that. I just added the last image to show you the thesis table of content section need to be edited. How am i suppose to edit it without editing .toc file manually??

Comment: @ichbinberk You are not supposed to edit the table of contents manually. It gets created automatically. You should make sure that the body of your document contains whatever sections etc. you want to have in the table of contents.

Comment: And don't forget: After a change of a `\section` or similar you need *two* LaTeX runs, to see the change also in the table of contents.